# Proper way to create two different objects in one Thymeleaf form

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am struggling with a problem - what is a proper (and working) way to create two objects in one Thymeleaf form. I have tried tons of solutions from Google, and can't find a working one.

I have three models and two superclasses:

Superclass 1:

```
// Lots of Lombok annotations
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    public boolean isNew() {
        return this.id == null;
    }

}
```

Superclass 2:

```
// Lots of Lombok annotations
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public class Ingredient extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name="name")
    protected String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient")
    private Set<BatchIngredient> batches = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Batch model:

```
// Lots of Lombok annotations
public class Batch extends BaseEntity {

    //fields, getters, setter...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "batch")
    private Set<BatchIngredient> ingredients = new HashSet<>();
    }
```

Malt model:

```
// Lots of Lombok annotations
public class Malt extends Ingredient {
//fields, getters, setter...
}
```

BatchIngredient model - association between Batch and Ingredients:

```
// Lots of Lombok annotations
@Table(name="batch_ingredient")
@IdClass(BatchIngredientId.class)
public class BatchIngredient {

    @Id
    private Long ingredientId;

    @Id
    private Long batchId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="amount")
    private int amount;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "way_of_serving")
    private String wayOfServing;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingredientId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Ingredient ingredient;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "batchId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Batch batch;

}
```

I'm using Batch controller to enter the form:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/batch")
class BatchController {

    @ModelAttribute("malts")
    public Set<Malt> populateMalts() {
        return maltService.findByOrderByNameAsc();
    }

    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String initCreationForm(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("batch", new Batch());
        model.addAttribute("batchIngredient", new BatchIngredient());

        return VIEWS_BATCH_CREATE_OR_UPDATE_FORM;
    }
    // other methods...
}
```

And this form to populate some Batch data:

```
<body>

    <form th:action="@{'/batch/saveBatch'}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name ="id" th:field="*{batch.id}">

                <label>Batch number:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{batch.batchNumber}"/>

                // lots of other input fields to populate Batch model...

                And here we have table in the form - here a I want to create "BatchIngredient" object, and in this example - pass to this object "Malt" from the drop-down field
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="thead">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr th:remove="all">
                        <td>Pale Ale</td>
                        <td>4000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" th:value="*{malt.id}">
                                <option th:each="malt : ${malts}"
                                        th:value="${malt?.id}"
                                        th:text="${malt?.name}">
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

        <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

I have no idea how to achieve this, or if it's even possible. Some advices?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to create a single object that has two objects as properties of it.  For example, something like:

```
public class BatchForm {
  private Batch batch;
  private BatchIngredient batchIngredient;

  // Getters and setters
}
```

Then add that onto your model, and work from there.  A sample form might look like (although I'm not quite sure where `malt.id` fits into Batch or BatchIngredient):

```
<form th:action="@{'/batch/saveBatch'}" th:object="batchForm" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name ="id" th:field="*{batch.id}">

  <select class="form-control" th:value="*{batchIngredient.malt.id}">
    <option th:each="malt : ${malts}" th:value="${malt?.id}" th:text="${malt?.name}" />
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Malt is an object added to BatchIngredient - otherwise, I'm not able to aasociate multiple Malt object with "amount" value to "Batch". I will try to use this approach on Monday.

Comment: Still trying to make this as you suggested, but with no luck. This is the repo: https://github.com/fangirsan/maruszka-new (post branch), if you would have time to look at this, I would be very grateful.